# Why is keras ResNet50's first maxpooling = 55x55 where in the paper it's 56x56?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use pre-trained ResNet50 from keras.application.resnet50 as encoder for my U-Net. I use input shape 224x224x3 (same as stated in the [ResNet paper](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/He_Deep_Residual_Learning_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf), page 4) but the output of my first residual block is 55 x 55 x #_filters.
On the paper the output size should be 56 x 56 x #_filters. This is important to me because I use skip connection from encoder to decoder as demonstrated in the picture below. 
[U-Net with ResNet50 as encoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ASNa.jpg)
The feature map from encoder is concatenated with feature map in decoder. The decoder has 56x56 feature map (upsampling from 28 x 28). If the encoder has 55 x 55 feature map, I cannot make this skip connection.

The example code in python:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50,preprocess_input
R50 = ResNet50(include_top = False, input_shape = (224, 224, 3))
R50.layers.pop() # to remove the last pooling layer
R50.summary()
```

The output:
[R50 summary output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q450j.jpg)
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/resnet50.py) and the first maxpooling:

```
x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)
```

cannot possibly produce output with size 56x56 when the input is 224. I think it is very likely that the correct maxpooing function should be

```
x = MaxPooling2D(3, 2, padding = 'same')(x)
```

I am not 100% sure but I think this should work for now. Please let me know if you think otherwise. Thank you.